# The renderer for class sap.ui.core.mvc.View is not defined or does not define a render function! Rendering will be skipped! -

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am learning SAPUI5. In the link [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CJVWaZc1OL2dKzU6qtIe?p=preview). I have a few question.
I am trying to create a JS view and a controller to play with. Why do I have to specify my app, page inside getCore(). what if I would do it outside getCore(). But once I initialize app and Page inside my core method, console is throwing an error. Detail explanation will be really helpful. Thanks :)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script
      id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
      src= "https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
      data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
      data-sap-ui-preload="async"
    ></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello SAPUI5</h1>
    <div class="sapUiBody" id="content"></div>
    <div id="content1"></div>
  </body>
```

```
// Code goes here
//debugger
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function(){
  new sap.m.Text({
    text:"Hello World, SAPUI5"
  }).placeAt("content");

  var app = new sap.m.App({
        initialPage : "idViewDashboard1"
    });

 var page = new sap.ui.core.mvc.View({
        id : "idViewDashboard1",
        viewName:"ViewChartContainer",
        type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
    });

    app.addPage(page);
    app.placeAt("content1");

});
```

`

> The renderer for class sap.ui.core.mvc.View is not defined or does not define a render function! Rendering of idViewDashboard1 will be skipped! -

Comment: About the `sap.ui.getCore().attachInit` method: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794033/is-it-really-required-to-listen-for-global-init-event-using-attachinit-functio/56796417

Answer (score 2):

`getCore()` returns the [Core](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Core.html) instance which has the [`attachInit()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Core.html#attachInit) event that

> will either be called as soon as the framework has been initialized
>   or, if it has been initialized already, it will be called immediately.

Because things are loaded asynchronously, attachInit is the best place build your app with the ui5 framework because you can rely on that everything is available and ready.

Your plunkr emits that rather obscure error message because you create an empty instance of the class sap.ui.core.mvc.View that is meant to be abstract and indeed has no renderer method. To [instantiate your view](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/68d0e58857a647d49470d9f92dd859bd.html) you should use the `sap.ui.view()` method:

```
var page = sap.ui.view({
        id : "idViewDashboard1",
        viewName:"viewChartContainer",
        type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
    });
```

See here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ErToSaYgyg7KJ3HX52Oj?p=preview

If you want to learn UI5 i can recommend you to read the [Walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html). There you can read about many more useful patterns other than that mentioned attachInit() like: encapsulate your app in a component, use XMLViews, use AMD-Modules,...

Comment: @ schnoedel Thank you so much. Its really helpful tip

Comment: @Megh Please click on the check mark to let others know that the issue is resolved by this answer.