# Is it really required to listen for global init event using "attachInit" function?

Tags: sapui5

I read it in many articles that, "it is a good practice to listen for global init event in order to trigger your application logic only after the event has been fired". But I tried to do otherwise still no problem occurs. When I check the network tab all, irrespective of the placement of the code, the core libraries are loaded first. Then the code dependent on libraries is loaded.

I tried searching for my answer but couldn't get a clear answer. I tried to check it using a sample code I wrote. But no success.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Pets</title>
        <script id="test"
            src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m">
        </script>
        <script>
            var oImage2 = new sap.m.Image({
                src: "img/cat_sad.jpg",
                decorative: false,
                alt: "sad cat"
            });
            oImage2.placeAt("content");
            alert("different_script_tag");
        </script>
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
                alert("inside_attachinit");
                var oImage1 = new sap.m.Image({
                    src: "img/dog_sad.jpg",
                    decorative: false,
                    alt: "sad dog"
                });
                oImage1.placeAt("content");
            });
            alert("outside_attachinit");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
    </body>
</html>
```

I wish to know, if browser already prioritizes the requests accordingly for us, why we are told to follow this good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only "a good practice", it's **absolutely necessary** in order to enable *[asynchronous loading](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/676b636446c94eada183b1218a824717)*.

Activating *asynchronous loading* of modules **requires listening to the `init` event**. Otherwise, the app will crash because you're trying to access `Image` from `sap.m` although that library hasn't been loaded yet:

> ```html
> <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
>   data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
>   data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m"
>   data-sap-ui-async="true"
> ></script>
> <script>
>   var oImage2 = new sap.m.Image(/*...*/); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Image' of undefined!
> </script>
> ```

---

If you're wondering why asynchronous loading is important, compare these two scenarios:

## 1. Without listening to `init` (no aync possible):

[image]

- Dependent libraries and other modules are retrieved sequentially one by one.
- It uses *[sync XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request)* which is deprecated.
- While the app loads, browser often freezes.
- Users usually need to wait longer until they see something.

## 2. With async (listening to `init` required):

[image]

- Files are retrieved in parallel asynchronously.
- No freezing behavior.

Depending on synchronous XHR is **not** future-proof and makes the app significantly slower.  As UI5 is getting better and better and preparing for further improvements, please keep following best-practices in order to "evolve" together with UI5.